# Gridview Rowcommand cell to public string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview, rowcommand

I have a gridview with a rowcommand event.

I would like the value of `temp` string to be used outside my rowcommand. 
Is this possible?

```
protected void gwActivity_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = ((e.CommandSource as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
   string temp = row.Cells[1].Text;  
}
```

Comment: Uhm, `this.Temp = temp;` What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes..... either pass temp to whatever needs as the scope currently means that variable dies as soon as its made. You could make it part of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a private field in your class like:

```
private string _temp;
```

and then assign your `temp` string to it:

```
protected void gwActivity_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = ((e.CommandSource as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
   string temp = row.Cells[1].Text;  

   _temp = temp;
}
```

Comment: Look how "easy" that was :) I learn something new everyday. Thank you!